# Toggle button inside map

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, toggle

I'm trying to set a toggle inside a map , it activates with a button , now i handled to difference between every single item of the card but there's one problem, since the state changes, i mean i'm not updating it, the state doesn't let me have several buttons activated, i tried making the initial state an array of objects but i can't upload one single position of the array...
here's the code:

**Handler**

```
 //hooks 
    const [detail, setDetail] = useState([{
        id: '',
        state: false,

    }]);

    const handleClick = (e, id) => {
        setDetail({ ...detail, id: id, state: !detail['state'] })
    }
```

**Map**

```
<div className={Styles.wrapper}>
                {
                    artistSales && artistSales.map(s => {

                        return (
                            <div className={Styles.align}>
                                <div className={Styles.card}>
                                    <div className={Styles.order}>
                                        <h2>Numero de orden: {s.id_order}</h2>
                                        <p>Estado de pago: {s.state === 'fullfilled' && 'pago realizado'} </p>
                                        <p>Cliente: {s.userId.name} {s.userId.lastname} </p>
                                        <p>Email:
                                <a href={`mailto:${s.userId.email}`}>{s.userId.email}</a>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className={Styles.detail}>
                                        <p>Total: ${s.total_price}</p>
                                        <p>Fecha: {s.createdAt.slice(0, 10)}</p>
                                        <button value={s.id_order} onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, s.id_order)} className={Styles.btn}>Ver detalles</button>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                {detail.id === s.id_order && detail.state === true && <div>
                                    hello
                                </div>}----> this is what should be displayed when you click the button
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to first find a matching id. if there is none you should add it to array, otherwise make a copy from the match with new state value.

you can create also a function to check if for a given id that specific state value to render your content logic:

```
const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);

const handleClick = (e, id) => {
  setDetails(details => {
    // find index for matching detail
    const detailIndex = details.findIndex(d => d.id === id)

    // no match return new state
    if (detailIndex === -1) {
      return [...details, { id, state: true }]
    }

    // with match create copy details
    const nextDetails = [...details]
    
    // create copy of detail with a flipped state value
    const state = !nextDetails[detailIndex].state
    nextDetails[detailIndex] = { ...nextDetails[detailIndex], state }

    return nextDetails
  })
}

// function to get artist detail state
const detailForArtist = ( id ) => {
  const detail = details.find(d => d.id === id)
  return detail?.state
}


{ detailForArtist(s.id_order) && <div>hello</div> }
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! This is the perfect answer ! :)